# How to correctly instantiate mContentView in RecyclerView's ViewHolder, to avoid Null Object Reference?

Tags: java, android

When I attempt to set a string as the value of mContentView for my ViewHolder, Android studio says that I am creating a null object reference:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
    holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).getName());

}
```

Error Message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gatech.astroworld.spacetrader, PID: 10155
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.gatech.astroworld.spacetrader.views.market.Buy_Item_RecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Buy_Item_RecyclerAdapter.java:49)
```

Basically, my question is: How do I instantiate mContentView, so I can avoid the null object reference?

Here is ViewHolder class:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public View mView;
    public TextView mIdView;
    public TextView mContentView;
    public Store.MarketGood mItem;
    public int textCount = 0;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        mIdView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_number);
        mContentView = view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        final TextView itemCountText = view.findViewById(R.id.countText);
        final TextView showName = view.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        Button plusButton = mView.findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
        Button minusButton = mView.findViewById(R.id.minusButton);


        plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //showName.setText(mItem.getName());
                store.incrementCountBuy(mItem);
                itemCountText.setText(String.valueOf(mItem.getCount()));
            }
        });

        minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                store.decrementCountBuy(mItem);
                itemCountText.setText(String.valueOf(mItem.getCount()));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is `mContentView`?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. Your current example is missing the declaration of your `ViewHolder` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my adapter as an example:

```
public class AdapterAssetList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAssetList.ViewHolderAssets> {
private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;

Context context;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public AdapterAssetList(Context mContext, ArrayList<Asset> assetList) {
    this.context = mContext;
    this.assetList = assetList;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolderAssets onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_asset_childs, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolderAssets viewHolderAssets = new ViewHolderAssets(view);
    return viewHolderAssets;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolderAssets holder, int position) {
    imageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    holder.assetName.setText(assetList.get(position).getName());
    holder.assetValue.setText(withSuffix((long) assetList.get(position).getValue()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (assetList == null)
        assetList = new ArrayList<>();
    return assetList.size();
}

public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}

public void removeAt(int position) {
    //subsPlanList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    //notifyItemRangeChanged(position, subsPlanList.size());
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position, String id);
}

public class ViewHolderAssets extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView assetName;
    TextView assetValue;


    public ViewHolderAssets(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        assetName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_asset_name);
        assetValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_asset_value);


    /**
     * Called when a view has been clicked.
     *
     * @param v The view that was clicked.
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), "copyright");
    }
}

}
```

Note: your ViewHOlder should be inner class of your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an inner class for your viewHolder and extend RecyclerView.ViewHolder. Then a add a method like *bindData* in your new viewHolder class and add user implementation. Once this is complete, call the bindData from the onBindViewHolder method.

Eg: https://github.com/Kartikkumargujarati/Android-RR/blob/b6baa006477377aeef6e614f4291760fff324dfb/Networking/app/src/main/java/com/kartik/networking/ui/GitHubListAdapter.kt#L26